# How to make non nested diagram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, node-connections

I am trying to draw a diagram in LaTeX but there is a problem which is I needed to made many lines to go to a specific output (Result), but they do a nested output..

look at the diagram that I have

[image]

The code that I was writing is this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}



\begin{document}


\newpage

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm, node distance=5em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{elli} = [draw, ellipse, fill=red!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm, node distance=5em]
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, fill=blue!50, text width=10em, text centered, minimum height=10mm, node distance=5em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block] (start) {1, 2};
\node[decision, below of=start, yshift=-5em](dec1) {...?};
\node[decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-8em](dec2) { 'Yes'?};
\node[decision, right of=dec2, xshift= 8em](dec3) { 'No'?};
\node[elli, below of=dec3, yshift=-5em, yshift=-1em](look) {look};
\node[decision, below of=look, yshift= -5em](dec4) {found?};
\node[elli, right of=dec4, xshift=10em](AddToYes) {Add to 'Yes'};
\node[elli, left of=dec4, xshift=-10em](AddToNo) {Add to 'No'};
\node[block, below of= AddToYes, yshift=-5em](Res) {Result};
%arrows
\path [line] (start) -- (dec1);
\path [line] (dec1) -- (dec2);
\path [line] (dec2) -- (dec3);
\path [line] (dec3) -- (look);
\path [line] (look) -- (dec4);
\path [line] (dec4) -- (AddToNo);
\path [line] (dec4) -- (AddToYes);
\path [line] (AddToYes) -- (Res);
\path [line] (AddToNo) |- (Res);
\path [line] (dec3) |- (Res);
\path [line] (dec2) |- (Res);
\path [line] (dec1) -| node[yshift=0.5em, xshift=-17em]{No} (Res);



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, This is the picture that I need, I draw it by hand [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8yDY.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8yDY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like the `chains` library for this or a matrix of nodes or both. I'm not entirely sure how the diagram should look, though.

Something like this??

[image: chained flow]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shadows, arrows, chains, scopes, positioning}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm},
  line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
  elli/.style = {draw, ellipse, fill=red!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm},
  block/.style = {draw, rectangle, fill=blue!50, text width=10em, text centered, minimum height=10mm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=first going below, node distance=5em, every join/.style={line}]
  \node [on chain, block] (start) {1, 2};
  \node [on chain, decision, join] (dec1) {...?};
  {[start branch=helper going left]
    \node [on chain, shape=coordinate] (helper) {};
  }
  \node [on chain, decision, join] (dec2) { 'Yes'?};
  {[start branch=no going right]
    \node [on chain, decision, join] (dec3) { 'No'?};
    {[continue chain=going below]
      \node [on chain, elli, join] (look) {look};
      \node [on chain, decision, join] (dec4)  {found?};
      {[start branch=add to no going right]
        \node [on chain, elli, join] (AddToYes) {Add to 'Yes'};
      }
      \node [on chain, elli, join] (AddToNo) {Add to 'No'};
    }
  }
  \node [on chain, below=of dec2 |- AddToNo, block, join] (res) {Result};
  \draw [line] (AddToNo) |- (res);
  \draw [line] (dec1) -- (helper) |- (res);
  \draw [line] (AddToYes) |- (res);
  \draw [line] (dec1) -| (AddToYes);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

Another possibility is, as I mentioned, to use the `matrix` library. For example, the following is based on your scanned diagram (so has no `elli` type nodes but you can easily adapt):

[image: matrix option]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, matrix, quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm},
  line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
  block/.style = {draw, rectangle, fill=blue!50, text width=10em, text centered, minimum height=10mm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto}]
  \matrix [matrix of nodes, column sep=5em, row sep=5em]
  {
    |(start) [block]| 1, 2 & & \\
    |(dec1) [decision]| \dots? & & \\
    |(yes) [decision]| `Yes' & & \\
    |(no) [decision]| `No' & & |(look) [block]| Look\dots \\
    & |(add2no) [block]| Add to `No' & |[decision] (found)| Found? \\
    & & |(add2yes) [block]| Add to `Yes' \\
    |(res) [block]| Result & & \\
  };
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {start/dec1/,dec1/yes/Yes,yes/no/No,no/look/No,no/res/Yes,found/add2no/No,found/add2yes/Yes,look/found/} \draw [line] (\i) edge ["\k"] (\j);
  \draw [line] (dec1.west) -- +(-5em,0) node [midway, above] {No}  |- (res);
  \draw [line] (add2yes) |- (res);
  \draw [line] (add2no) |- (res);
  \draw [line] (yes.west) -- +(-2.5em,0) node [midway, above] {Yes} |- (res);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer, it works, but I amend something. I really would like to vote up, but I need to get more point to be able to do so. Thanks cfr

Comment: @aamls Please see edit. May a matrix would work better in your case?

Comment: REALLY GREAT ANSWER .. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I COULD NOT UPVOTE IT BECAUSE I SHOULD HAVE A BETTER REPUTATION, BUT IT IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEED.

Comment: @aamls Glad it helps! If you wish (you don't have to), you can accept the answer by clicking on the greyed out tick at the top left of it. This is entirely up to you: you can wait for a better answer, accept this one and then change your mind, or accept no answer at all. But you don't need any reputation to accept answers - just you can only accept one per question, of course. (That is, if you accept one then accept another, you unaccept the first....)